# Inserting Highcharts bar graph into sharepoint 2013 page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, highcharts

I am trying to insert a bar graph for my Sharepoint list but I can't get it to display for some reason. The list is called "GPS III Cause Codes" and has two columns. Column 1 has a name and column 2 has a value from a dropdown choice menu. How can I change the code below so that it counts the number of occurrences for each value in column 2 and creates a bar graph?

Example data:

```html
|Column 1  |  Column 2 
---------------------------
| Bob      | Option 1
| Dave     | Option 2 
| Tom      | Option 1 
| Dan      | Option 5
| Jason    | Option 1
```

Could someone let me know where I am missing something?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var splistitems;
var seriesarray = new Array();

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetChartData, "sp.js");

function GetChartData() {
   seriesarray = [];
   var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('GPS III Cause Codes');
   var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   splistitems = splist.getItems(splistquery);
   currentcontext.load(splistitems);
   currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, GetChartDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, GetChartDataFail));
}

function GetChartDataSuccess(sender, args) {
   var splistitemcount = splistitems.get_count();
   if (splistitemcount != 0) {
      var splistitemenumerator = splistitems.getEnumerator();
      while (splistitemenumerator.moveNext()) {
         var currentlistitem = splistitemenumerator.get_current();
         var itemname = currentlistitem.get_item("Title");
         var causecode = currentlistitem.get_item("Cause Code");
         var seriesitem = {
                           name: itemname,
                           data: [ causecode ]
                       };
         seriesarray.push(seriesitem);
      }
      DrawChart();
   }
}


function GetChartDataFail(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function DrawChart() {
        fruitChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Cause Code Trends'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Discussion', 'Document/Procedure Request', 'Data Request', 'SpaceX response/clarification', 'Identification','Documentation Error', 'Missing Testing Results', 'Out of Tolerance Results'] 
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of Requests'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                false
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: seriesarray
        });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You code contains errors ... Did you try to see what your browser console returns ? This part:

```
legend: {
     false
}
```

has incorrect syntax. It should be:

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Then, the format of your `seriesarray` is not correct for what you want to draw. You should give an array of this format:

```
[{name: name, y: value},...]
```

So your code becomes:

```
var seriesitem = {
      name: itemname,
      y: count
};
seriesarray.push(seriesitem);
```

And in the chart definitions, change xAxis to:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The input data is actually a little different from what I originally described. I have a list of Names in column A and in column B there is one of 5 options for the Name. Do you know how I could change this code to count the number of occurrences of each value in column B to get a bar graph? I revised my original question with some example data from the Sharepoint list.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. What is wrong with your code ?

Comment: The code assumes that column B is integers, or a count of each item in column A. However, the data I have is not formatted like that. The data in column B is just the name of the option, so I need the code to bin the options in column B into groups, and then graph those groups.

Comment: So in your code, what is referring to this column B? Is it the `itemname` variable in the loop ?

Comment: That's where I'm not quite sure how to structure the code - I am not familiar with the javascript behind the highcharts. I had meant for the "Title" to be Column A and the "Cause Code" column to be Column B, however that is definitely not working. Do you know how I could structure the code to bin the items in Column B and display a graph of them? Essentially Column A is not necessary. I am just interested in a pie chart of sorts of the items in column B.

Comment: This is not a complicated algorithm. Just get your column B as an array and loop trough to get what you want. You wan easily find a way to get the correct count ;)